# PayPal buy now / shopping cart with and without postage assistance

Tags: paypal

I am looking for assistance with multiple buttons on a page, some which have postage and nultiple items, some without or free postage.

At present i have a standard shopping cart option on a page created from the standard create button PayPal page, which provides a space for the buyer to type in their requirements with includes free postage and works fine.

A second shopping cart on the same page offers a similar buyer feature but adds postage, all works fine.

Third, fourth and fifth buying options are single buy now buttons each with added postage.

But the problem for the buyer is that when they a add a single item with postage and a multi-buy shopping cart option, they end up with duplicate postage...

If they buy 2 single items using the buy now buttons + a multi-buy they end up having three duplicate postage costs in their order.

Any suggestions welcomed to avoid duplication of postage costs, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you currently have the shipping set up (whether via the buttons themselves or the shipping profile), but this is how I would tackle this:

For the items that are free shipping, within the shipping option in the button itself I would set a shipping cost of 0.00. Then set up the shipping calculations section in Tools or your Profile for your shipping rates for the items that do have shipping costs. In the last step of the shipping calculations creation, you want the box to be checked to use the shipping cost in the transaction instead of your calculator settings and that will allow the buttons you have a shipping cost entered directly into to override the shipping costs you set in the shipping calculator.

If you need any assistance setting up the shipping calculator you may call into PayPal Support and they can assist you.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, very interesting. 

I tried phoning support who put me through to the tech support and they said it was not possible to do what I'd asked, and stated that Paypal are a card transaction merchant by default, and are not developers, as this would be too costly. They suggested I should look at magento as a paid solution. 

I'll have a read up about your suggestion.

Regards 

Alan